# How to Create Party Object from a String?

Tags: corda

Given **mystring = "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"**, is there an easy method to convert the string into a real Party object?  Have been looking at **CordaRPCOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name()** but cannot get it to work...  Have tried variations of the following:

```
val rpcOps = new CordaRPCOps()
val otherParty: Party = rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyString) ?: throw Exception("Party not recognised.")
```

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways you can do this:

**Parsing the string into an X500 name**

```
val x500Name = CordaX500Name.parse("O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US")
val party = rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(x500Name)
```

**Constructing the X500 name directly**

```
val x500Name = CordaX500Name(organisation = "PartyB", locality = "New York", country = "US")
val party = rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(x500Name)
```

**Fuzzy matching**

```
val matchingParties = rpcOps.partiesFromName("PartyB", false)
if (matchingParties.size != 1) {
    throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
val party2 = matchingParties.single()
```

**Getting an CordaRPCOps instance**

Here's an example of how you'd get a CordaRPCOps instance in the first place:

```
val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
val cordaRPCOps = rpcConnection.proxy
```

Comment: I will try those methods, but first am having trouble creating an instance of rpcOps.  Have tried  `val thisParty = CordaRPCOps().wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyString)` but this   results in  `Error:(8, 21) Kotlin: Interface CordaRPCOps does not have constructors`.  Also tried `val rpcOps = CordaRPCOps` which results in `Error:(11, 18) Kotlin: Classifier 'CordaRPCOps' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here`. Is there a trick to creating an instance of CordaRPCOps?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also get the Party instance without using `CordaRPCOps`. But this solution requires you to have access to the ServiceHub instance. This means you can access it from a `CordaService`. Let's say `serviceHub` is a `CordaService` instance. Then, try the following:

```
val x500Name = CordaX500Name.parse("O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US")
val party: Party? = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getPeerByLegalName(x500Name)
```

This will handy in case you require `Party` instance from `String` in a Corda service,  where it is unnecessary to create an RPC connection.